# Pulling information from a previous webpage error (Angular2, Typescript, javascript, html)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm making an ebay clone website that makes an auction/bidding system from wikipedia search results.

Screenshot of search results: [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryTlh.png)

Screenshot of the different webpage (The "Apple" in this screenshot should instead say "A"): [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xof4L.png)

I'm trying to make this variable consistent:

- item.name

Screenshot of error when trying to get {{item.name}} consistent: dropbox.com/s/wlcovvt8x5v7cne/screenthis.png?dl=0

Code of `biddingpage.component.html` that causes error:

```
 <label for="name">Name of item: {{item.name}} </label>
        <p>
          </p>
```

Link to full project: dropbox.com/s/84svnggv8xeub5m/FullProjectEbayClone.zip?dl=0

Name of code files I am changing:

- wiki.component.ts
- biddingpage.component.html
- biddingpage.component.ts

Link to plunker of full project (currently not working): plnkr.co/edit/1lcI4dURHwA8D9IQtqSf?p=info

Code of wiki.component.ts:

```
import { Component }        from 'angular2/core';
import { JSONP_PROVIDERS }  from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs';
import { WikipediaService } from './wikipedia.service';
import {Router, RouteParams, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'Wikithing',
  template: `
    <h1>Search and Display Page</h1>
    <p><i>Fetches after each keystroke</i></p>
    <input #term (keyup)="search(term.value)"/>
    <ul>
     <li *ngFor="#item of items | async">{{item}} <br> <p> 

     </p> Price (in USD): $ {{item.price}} <br> <p>

      </p> Availability: 24 hours <br> <p> 

      </p> Quantity currently in stock: {{quantity}}

       <br> <p> 

      </p> Image of item: <img src="http://weknowyourdreamz.com/images/apple/apple-05.jpg" alt="Apple" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
       <br> <p> 
       </p>
               <p>

            </p>
             <a [routerLink]="['BiddingPage']">Click here to bid on this item.</a>
            <p>

                </p>
        <br> <p> 
       </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers:[JSONP_PROVIDERS, WikipediaService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink],

})
export class WikiComponent {
  constructor (private wikipediaService: WikipediaService) {}
  items: Observable<string[]>;




  search (term: string) {
    this.items = this.wikipediaService.search(term);
    this.items.map((items) => items.map(() => ({
      name: items,
      prices: Math.random(),
      quantity: Math.random(),
      availability: Math.random()
    })));

    var Prices = Math.random() + Math.random();
    var quantity = Math.random();
  }

}
```

Comment: The Plunker is way too complex. Please create one that contains only what is necessary to reproduce the problem at hand. I don't understand the question. What does "pulling onformation from a previous webpage" mean? What's the actual problem?

Comment: @Gunter Zochbauer I'm trying to solve this error by finding a way to get the name of the item then displaying that name where it says "Apple" in the second screenshot (whatever the user types into the search box) Here's the screenshot of the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlcovvt8x5v7cne/screenthis.png?dl=0